# Material-table package with Material UI v5 styles overwritten when table is rendered?

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, material-table

In the project we are using material ui version 5   `"@mui/material": "^5.13.2",`   `"@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",` and we are also using npm package material-table with version   `"material-table": "^1.69.3",`,

So whenever this Table is rendered all MUI styles are overwritten, and page has completely wrong look. Without table page is looking good.

I know the issue is with mismach the versions of MUI and this package, but is there any solutions to overcome this, so this npm material-table can be used with MUI version 5 or simply we need to move away from this package?

Thanks